# Error when using unicode-math/mathrm in a glossary entry

Tags: luatex, glossaries, unicode-math

This error seems to occur since I updated the TeX Live 2017 packages. When I try to use `\mathrm` in a `\newglossaryentry`, it results in in two errors:

! Missing { inserted.
 
__um_group_begin: 
l.83    \gls{sFSW} 
               \gls{HIL}
A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.

! Missing } inserted.
 
}
l.83    \gls{sFSW} 
               \gls{HIL}
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the  above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

Also, using e.g. `$F_\mathrm{SW}$` within the document results in the same errors.

Without the `unicode-math` package or when not using `\mathrm` in the glossary entry, I receive no errors.

(Almost) MWE:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,                            % alle weiteren Papierformate einste
headsepline,                        % Trennline zum Seitenkopf  
headings=normal,                
listof=totoc, version=first,        % Abb.- und Tab.verzeichnis im Inhalt
bibliography=totoc, version=first,  % Literaturverzeichnis im Inhalt
numbers=noenddot,                   % Keine Endpunkte wie 1.2. sondern 1.2
]
{scrbook}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools}      % includes: \usepackage{amsmath} (-> needed e.g. for bmatrix) !! load BEFORE \usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{unicode-math}   % Unicode mathematics support for X∃TEX and LuaTEX

% Set font 
%\setromanfont{Cambria}
%\setsansfont{Calibri}
%\setmonofont{Consolas}
%\setmathfont{Cambria Math}

\usepackage[  %Paket Glossaries laden, muss nach Hyperref geladen werden!
xindy,
nonumberlist, % keine Seitenzahlen anzeigen           
acronym,      % ein Abkürzungsverzeichnis erstellen
toc           % Einträge im Inhaltsverzeichnis
] 
{glossaries}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Table of Symbols}
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}

%Glossar-Befehle anschalten
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sFSW}{
    name=\ensuremath{{F_\mathrm{SW}}},
    description={Driver force, generated by steering wheel moment, acting on the gear rack.},
    sort=FSW, type=symbolslist
}  
% Acronyms
\newacronym{HIL}{HIL}{Hardware-in-the-Loop}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=long]
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=Acronyms, nonumberlist=true, toctitle=Acronyms]

\mainmatter                     % Hauptteil
\pagenumbering{arabic}

    \chapter{Test}
    \gls{sFSW} \gls{HIL}

    $F_\mathrm{SW}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `F_\mathrm{SW}` is wrong and it happens to work with `pdflatex` just by chance.

The correct syntax is, and always has been, `F_{\mathrm{SW}}`.

So just do

```
\newglossaryentry{sFSW}{
  name=\ensuremath{F_{\mathrm{SW}}},
  description={Driver force, generated by steering wheel moment, acting on the gear rack.},
    sort=FSW, type=symbolslist
}
```

and your problem will be solved.

---

The apparent success of `F_\mathrm{SW}` is due to how `\mathrm` is implemented in the LaTeX kernel. However, `unicode-math` must implement it in a different way, which makes the *unsupported* syntax to fail.

Comment: I did not know this and always used it wrong. Thank you!